# What do you normally do to write composite functions in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I want to do the following:

```
getCH[pts_List] := Module[{t}, t = ConvexHull[pts]; Map[Part[pts, #] &, t]];
```

or

```
Map[Function[{x}, Part[#, x]], ConvexHull[#]]&
```

What are other ways to write this? And how do you normally do for speed and efficiency?

**Edit**

BTW, I am asking this in a generic way, not for this particular problem. I sometimes feel the lack of brain power to think in terms of functional programming in mma. Just want to expand my arsenal with various other ways to write function compositions and learn the analysis of their complexity/efficiency. So please add similar problems.

Comment: Sorry I only just saw your edit. The distinction between `Module` for local variables and `With` for local constants is generic.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what a ConvexHull is but I'll assume I understood the problem

```
    getCH[pts_]:=pts[[ConvexHull[pts]]]


    getCH[pts_]:=Extract[pts, Transpose@{ConvexHull[pts]}]
```

If you want pts to appear only once for some reason you could always use With, Module or Block. I think most important is to say that I don't see the point in doing that. With, effectively replaces each appearance of pts with the list of points. Seems like an overkill for this but feel free to write

```
     getCH[pts_]:=With[{p=pts},p[[ConvexHull[p]]]]
```

Module creates a new variable. It's usually slower than With for cases in which your variable doesn't need to be asigned a value. In other words, With is faster for defining constants. Block I think is also faster than Module (slightly) but its dynamic scoping (against Module's lexical scoping) makes it a little bit weirder. Lots of threads about these.

I don't think there's any built-in function that takes a list and a function or symbol, and extracts elements on that list indexed by the result of evaluating the function on that same list, if that's what you were looking for for your "generic" problem. Of course you can create one easily and then use it in the future. I think it's too much for such a simple issue but perhaps its the functional programming you were aiming for

```
    ExtractIndexed[l_List, fun_]:=l[[fun[l]]]

    getCH[pts_]:=ExtractIndexed[pts, ConvexHull]
```

Comment: You can also consider `List /@ ...` instead of `Transpose@{...}`.

Comment: @Szabolcs List/@ is probably clearer and as efficient in this case, but I have the habit of choosing Transpose when it fits for these things... Seems to be faster. Map is more general than Transpose which requires a List, a square matrix, etc

Comment: Yes, your are right, for packed arrays it is definitely much faster.  For curiosity, `Partition[..., 1]` is an equally fast (arguable less readable) alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize variables in a `Module` like this

```
Module[{t = ConvexHull[pts]}, Map[Part[pts, #] &, t]]
```

But in this case, you aren't redefining `t`, so it is a local constant and you are better off using `With`.

```
With[{t = ConvexHull[pts]}, Map[Part[pts, #] &, t]]
```

Or just

```
Map[Part[pts, #] &, ConvexHull[pts] ]
```

Or

```
Part[pts, #] & /@ ConvexHull[pts]
```

This question is related: [Using nested slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920194/using-nested-slots). It is not recommended to nest pure functions without naming variables.

You could “invert” your function like so, but I can't guarantee it works.

```
Function[x,Part[#,x]]& /@ ConvexHull[#] & @ pts
```

Comment: If I want to have `pts` just appear once, and also get rid of `Function` in `Map[Function[{x}, Part[#, x]], ConvexHull[#]]&`, is there a way, such as using @, /@, ~, etc?

Comment: And normally I really don't want to write pts twice.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try using `Through`:

```
Part @@ Through[ 
 List[ Identity, Graphics`Mesh`ConvexHull][{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {.5, .5}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]
]
```

This one gives a warning (because `Part` evaluates), but then 'works':

```
Through[
 Part[Identity, Graphics`Mesh`ConvexHull][{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {.5, .5}, {1, 1}, {0, 
 1}}]]
```

I think this is a way around the `Part` evaluating issue above:

```
Through[
 Unevaluated[
  Part[
   Identity, Graphics`Mesh`ConvexHull][
   {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {.5, .5}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}
]]]
```