# Mathematica : Write matrix-data to XML ; Read matrix-data from XML

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

( Part of ) a matrix representation of the objects I work with is the following:

```
 {
 {1, A,{100,  20, 30},10},
 {2, B,{100}, 0},
 {3, X,{120,20},0},
 {4, C,{},11}
 }
```

I want to store this data externally in XML Format as follows

<data>
<row key="1" val1="A" val2="10"> <occ>100</occ><occ>20</occ><occ>30</occ></row>
<row key="2" val1="B" val2="0"><occ>100</occ></row>
<row key="3" val1="X" val2="0"><occ>120</occ><occ>20</occ></row>
<row key="4" val1="C" val2="11"></row>
</data>

I am looking for an example on how to:

#### -  transfer the the matrix to XML ( which Mathematica commands ? )

#### -  parse the XML string back to matrix format after having imported the XML file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we import your data as symbolic XML:

```
In[50]:= xml = Import["C:\\Temp\\matrixData.xml"]

Out[50]= XMLObject["Document"][{}, 
 XMLElement["data", {}, 
 {XMLElement["row", {"key" -> "1", "val1" -> "A", "val2" -> "10"}, 
      {XMLElement["occ", {}, {"100"}], XMLElement["occ", {}, {"20"}], 
        XMLElement["occ", {}, {"30"}]}], 
  XMLElement["row", {"key" -> "2", "val1" -> "B", "val2" -> "0"},
      {XMLElement["occ", {}, {"100"}]}],
  XMLElement[ "row", {"key" -> "3", "val1" -> "X","val2" -> "0"}, 
      {XMLElement["occ", {}, {"120"}], XMLElement["occ", {}, {"20"}]}], 
  XMLElement["row", {"key" -> "4", "val1" -> "C", "val2" -> "11"}, {}]}], {}]
```

Here we parse into a matrix:

```
In[51]:= matr = 
 xml /. XMLObject["Document"][{}, data_, _] :> data /. 
     XMLElement["data", _, children_] :> children /. 
         XMLElement["row", attrs_, vals_] :> {"key" /. attrs, 
             "val1" /. attrs, vals /. XMLElement["occ", _, {val_}] :> val, 
             "val2" /. attrs} /. s_String :> ToExpression[s]

 Out[51]= {{1, A, {100, 20, 30}, 10}, {2, B, {100}, 0}, {3,X, {120, 20}, 0}, {4, C, {}, 11}}
```

The code is short and economical due to the use of rule-within-a-rule technique. I discuss it [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node346.html). One nice application of this technique can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451802/pattern-to-match-only-children-of-certain-elements/6453681#6453681).

Here is the reverse:

```
XMLObject["Document"][{}, XMLElement["data", {},
  Replace[matr, {key_, val1_, vals_List, val2_} :>
      XMLElement[ "row", {"key" -> ToString[key], "val1" -> ToString[val1], 
          "val2" -> ToString[val2]},
             XMLElement["occ", {}, {ToString[#]}] & /@ vals], {1}]], {}]
```

I do not show the result but it is the same as the imported symbolic XML. You can call `Export` with this symbolic XML and it will know how to handle it.

Comment: @ndroock1 Thanks for the accept. By the way, when parsing from XMK to matrix, I assumed that you want `A`,`B`, etc as symbols. If you want them as strings, change the rule `s_String :> ToExpression[s]` to `s_String/;StringMatchQ[s,NumberString] :> ToExpression[s]`, so that only numbers get parsed.