# Problems with Mathematica's Solve handling composite expressions as variables

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Solving the following equations

```
eq =
{
0 == e["P", {m["f6p", "c"], m["atp", "c"]}, {}, {}]*
 k["1", False] - e["P", {m["f6p", "c"]}, {}, {}]*m["atp", "c"]*
 k["1", True] - 
 e["P", {m["f6p", "c"]}, {}, {}]*k["2", False] + 
 e["P", {}, {}, {}]*m["f6p", "c"]*k["2", True], 
0 == -(e["P", {m["fdp", "c"]}, {}, {}]*m["adp", "c"]*
 k["3", False]) + 
 e["P", {m["fdp", "c"], m["adp", "c"]}, {}, {}]*
 k["3", True] + 
 e["P", {}, {}, {}]*m["fdp", "c"]*k["4", False] - 
 e["P", {m["fdp", "c"]}, {}, {}]*k["4", True], 
0 == -(e["P", {m["f6p", "c"], m["atp", "c"]}, {}, {}]*
 k["1", False]) + e["P", {m["f6p", "c"]}, {}, {}]*m["atp", "c"]*
 k["1", True] + 
 e["P", {m["fdp", "c"], m["adp", "c"]}, {}, {}]*k["5", False] - 
 e["P", {m["f6p", "c"], m["atp", "c"]}, {}, {}]*k["5", True], 
0 == e["P", {m["fdp", "c"]}, {}, {}]*m["adp", "c"]*
 k["3", False] - e["P", {m["fdp", "c"], m["adp", "c"]}, {}, {}]*
 k["3", True] - 
 e["P", {m["fdp", "c"], m["adp", "c"]}, {}, {}]*k["5", False] + 
 e["P", {m["f6p", "c"], m["atp", "c"]}, {}, {}]*k["5", True], 
0 == eTotal - e["P", {}, {}, {}] - 
 e["P", {m["f6p", "c"]}, {}, {}] - 
 e["P", {m["fdp", "c"]}, {}, {}] - 
 e["P", {m["f6p", "c"], m["atp", "c"]}, {}, {}] - 
 e["P", {m["fdp", "c"], m["adp", "c"]}, {}, {}]
};
```

for

```
vars=
{
 e["P",{},{},{}],
 e["P",{m["f6p","c"]},{},{}],
 e["P",{m["fdp","c"]},{},{}],
 e["P",{m["f6p","c"], m["atp","c"]},{},{}],
 e["P",{m["fdp","c"], m["adp","c"]},{},{}]
};
```

using Solve, yields two different results (depending on the approach chosen):

(1) Solving 'as is':

```
sol = Solve[eq, vars][[1]];
sol[[2]] /. {catch_e :> catch, m["adp", "c"] -> 0}
```

returns

```
e["P", {m["f6p", "c"]}, {}, {}] -> 0
```

which is simply wrong. Read [Prohibit replacement by ReplaceAll (/.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127419/prohibit-replacement-by-replaceall), if you're wondering about

```
{catch_e :> catch, m["adp", "c"] -> 0}
```

(2) Anonymize, Solve, Back-translation
Anonymizing the whole system (using Unique[]), solving, and back-translating

```
anon = # -> Unique[] & /@ Cases[eq, (_m | _e | _k), \[Infinity]];
revAnon = Reverse /@ anon;
anonEq = eq /. anon;
anonVars = vars /. anon;
sol2 = Solve[anonEq, anonVars][[1]] /. revAnon;
sol2[[2]] /. {catch_e :> catch, m["adp", "c"] -> 0}
```

returns something different

```
e[P,{m[f6p,c]},{},{}]->(eTotal (k[1,False] k[2,True] k[3,True] k[4,True] m[f6p,c]+k[1,False] k[2,True] k[4,True] k[5,False] m[f6p,c]+k[2,True] k[3,True] k[4,True] k[5,True] m[f6p,c]))/(k[1,False] k[2,False] k[3,True] k[4,True]+k[1,False] k[2,False] k[4,True] k[5,False]+k[2,False] k[3,True] k[4,True] k[5,True]+k[1,True] k[3,True] k[4,True] k[5,True] m[atp,c]+k[1,False] k[2,True] k[3,True] k[4,True] m[f6p,c]+k[1,False] k[2,True] k[4,True] k[5,False] m[f6p,c]+k[2,True] k[3,True] k[4,True] k[5,True] m[f6p,c]+k[1,True] k[2,True] k[3,True] k[4,True] m[atp,c] m[f6p,c]+k[1,True] k[2,True] k[4,True] k[5,False] m[atp,c] m[f6p,c]+k[1,True] k[2,True] k[3,True] k[5,True] m[atp,c] m[f6p,c]+k[1,True] k[2,True] k[4,True] k[5,True] m[atp,c] m[f6p,c]+k[1,False] k[2,False] k[3,True] k[4,False] m[fdp,c]+k[1,False] k[2,False] k[4,False] k[5,False] m[fdp,c]+k[2,False] k[3,True] k[4,False] k[5,True] m[fdp,c]+k[1,True] k[3,True] k[4,False] k[5,True] m[atp,c] m[fdp,c])
```

wich is correct.

I have no clear idea why this is happening, only speculations. Using something else than Symbols as variables must be the problem, as replacing all those complicated expressions by real Symbols makes the difference. Has anyone ever had a problem like this? Using these nested expressions (together with custom notations in the notebook interface) is my way of keeping track of variables and parameters in large problems. It would very frustrating if I had to abandon this habit.

**Update:**
Something I should have done before posting the question (I changed the variable name that contains the solution from the anonymizing approach to sol2 in the problem description):

```
testRules = # -> RandomReal[] & /@ 
    Union@Cases[{sol[[2, 2]], 
      sol2[[2, 2]]}, (_m | _e | _k), \[Infinity]];
(sol[[2, 2]] /. testRules) == (sol2[[2, 2]] /. testRules)
```

yields `True`. So both solutions are actually correct, they are just differently arranged.

Following Mr.Wizard's suggestion/post (using Simplify):

```
sol[[2, 2]] === sol2[[2, 2]]
```

yields `False`, while

```
Simplify[sol[[2, 2]]] === Simplify[sol2[[2, 2]]]
```

yields True.

Comment: Do you get the correct answer if you replace just the `String` elements such as "1", "2" etc with their `Integer` equivalents, and `True` and `False` with their `Boole` equivalents? Similarly, do you get the correct answer if you do that, plus changing the arguments to `m` into `Symbols`, i.e. `m[fdp,c]` rather than `m["fdp","c"]`?

Comment: @Verbeia `sol = Solve[eq /. s_String :> ToExpression[s], 
    vars /. s_String :> ToExpression[s]][[1]];
sol[[2]] /. {catch_e :> catch, m[adp, c] -> 0}` still yields the wrong  answer. Replacing `True` and `False` with `1` and `0` doesn't help either.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard so you say that one has to limit variable declarations to `Symbols`? In that case, shouldn't `Solve` raise at least a warning?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, this works `Solve[{a[1] == b[1] + b[2], a[2] == b[1] - b[2]}, {b[1], b[2]}]`, so why not the more exotic forms used by the OP?

Comment: @rcollyer I guess I was just professing my ignorance.  I have seen indexed or subscripted symbols, but not expressions this large.  I thought it might be causing a problem, but then I realized it was probably the simpler divide-by-zero.  I shall remove my comments above so as not to confuse others.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, definitely confusing to read at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I add `Simplify`:

```
sol = Solve[eq, vars][[1]] // Simplify;
sol[[2]] /. {catch_e :> catch, m["adp", "c"] -> 0}
```

I get:

```
e["P", {m["f6p", "c"]}, {}, {}] ->
    (eTotal (k["1", False] k["2", 
        True] (k["3", True] k["4", True] + 
         k["4", True] k["5", False]) m["f6p", "c"] + 
      k["2", True] k["3", True] k["4", True] k["5", True] m["f6p", 
        "c"]))/(k["1", True] k["3", True] k["4", True] k["5", True] m[
      "atp", "c"] + 
    k["2", True] k["3", True] k["4", True] k["5", True] m["f6p", 
      "c"] + k["1", True] k["2", True] k["3", True] k["4", True] m[
      "atp", "c"] m["f6p", "c"] + 
    k["1", True] k["2", True] k["4", True] k["5", False] m["atp", 
      "c"] m["f6p", "c"] + 
    k["1", True] k["2", True] k["3", True] k["5", True] m["atp", 
      "c"] m["f6p", "c"] + 
    k["1", True] k["2", True] k["4", True] k["5", True] m["atp", 
      "c"] m["f6p", "c"] + 
    k["1", True] k["3", True] k["4", False] k["5", True] m["atp", 
      "c"] m["fdp", "c"] + 
    k["2", False] k["3", True] k["5", 
      True] (k["4", True] + k["4", False] m["fdp", "c"]) + 
    k["1", False] (k["2", 
         True] (k["3", True] k["4", True] + 
          k["4", True] k["5", False]) m["f6p", "c"] + 
       k["2", False] (k["4", True] k["5", False] + 
          k["4", False] k["5", False] m["fdp", "c"] + 
          k["3", True] (k["4", True] + k["4", False] m["fdp", "c"]))))
```

How does that look?  If I don't use Simplify I get a divide by zero error due to the replacement.

Comment: I think you're right. The unsimplified answer has m["adb","c"] in the numerator, possibly causing the collapse to zero?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard After all, it seems that `Solve` can handle arbitrary expressions as variables, it's just confusing that the arrangement of the solution equations seems to non unique. Thank you for bringing up the `Simplify` issue.