# Is mathematica a functional programming language?

Tags: functional-programming, wolfram-mathematica

Is mathematica a functional programming language? what i intend to ask his that i keep reading that mathematica is a conditional rewrite  system. I want to know what is this conditional rewrite system?

I also wanted to know whether we can apply the functional programming concepts like continuous passing style, memoization etc using mathematica language?

Comment: You might get better answers to this on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/  But, while I'm writing: it's a moot point what Mathematica *is*, but you can certainly program in a functional style using Mathematica, and apply all the concepts you mention.  I'm not familiar with the term *conditional rewrite system* but it's often useful to think of Mathematica as a *term rewrite system*, start your learning at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_system

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mathematica: what is symbolic programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430998/mathematica-what-is-symbolic-programming)

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica supports multiple programming paradigms (procedural, functional and even object oriented). You can do CPS, memorization etc using the Mathematica language. But Mathematica is more about getting things done. If you want to learn more about the theory behind functional programming, I suggest using Scheme, Haskell, or ML as your vehicle.